# Modelformset and ajax submit to update models

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

How I can upload a model through jquery ".on", with modelformset?
In my case, the forms.py is

```
class ObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ['booleanfield']
```

myview in views.py:

```
...
objectformset_gen = modelformset_factory(Object, form=ObjectForm)
objectformset = objectformset_gen()
context.update({'objectformset': objectformset})
...
```

The template:

```
<form>
{{ objectformset.management_form }}
{% for form in objectformset %}
    {{ form.instance.NOTSERIAZABLEfields }}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
$("body").on("click", "input:checkbox", function(e){  //I know it is mad every input:checkbox
var data = JSON.stringify({form: $(this)});
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'myview' %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success:function(response){},
                    complete:function(){},
                    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
```

I think that in this case it is better if I don't use forms and formsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way. I used Modelformset only to render html forms but the view parse the request.body on low level to update the models.